How to design this sidebar in tvOS?

I presume this is a NavigationSplitView and the menu on the left is the sidebar closure. But I'm not quite sure how to reproduce this menu style in SwiftUI. There are very little docs or guides on how to develop and style tvOS apps.

Hello, Did you manage to resolve this?
